# When I hover my mouse over a YouTube video I want to then run a Python script that will download that video to my computer

Tags: python-3.x, youtube-dl

Put simply: When I hover my mouse over a YouTube video I want to run a Python script that will download that video to my computer.

In more detail: let's say I am looking at a list of videos at YouTube.com. Let's say I want to download one of those videos. How can I modify the Python script below so that it will "copy and paste" the URL of the YouTube video my cursor is hovering over into the Python script below so that the Python script below will download that video to my computer?

The following script will download a YouTube video...

```
# ydl1.py
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import youtube_dl

ydl_opts = {}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download(['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dP15zlyra3c'])
```

but currently I need to manually paste the URL of the video I want to download into the script above.

Comment: You cannot do that on youtube.com. You must serve a page with embedded videos and then trigger an action (maybe ajax?) responding on `onmouseover` event

Comment: Could I possibly use, for example, Pyautogui or Pyperclip to "copy and paste" the URL of the YouTube video which my mouse was hovering over?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know enough about that modules

Comment: Pyautogui is fairly simple. Here, take a look... https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html